# Partial match string in two dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. df1 contains partial names of persons and df2 contains names of persons, their dob, etc. I want to partially match df1['Partial_names'] column with df2['Full_names'] column. For example, to match Martin Lues all rows in Full_names Having Martin in them should be fetched. In Resulting dataframe should be

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame() 
df2 = pd.Dataframe()

df1['Partial_names'] = ['John Smith','Leo Lauana' ,'Adam Marry', 'Martin Lues']
df2['Full_names'] = ['John Smith Wade', 'Adam Blake Marry', 'Riley 
Leo Lauana', 'Martin Smith', 'Martin Flex Leo']

    Partial_names             
1   John Smith                         
2   Leo Lauana                     
3   Adam Marry                     
4   Martin Lues                                                                            
5   Martin Author             
                              

   Full_names
1  Martin Smith
2  Riley Leo Lauana
3  Adam Blake Marry
4  Jeff Hard Jin
5  Martin Flex Leo

      Partial_names              Resulting_Column_with_full_names
1     John Smith                 John Smith Wade
2     Leo Lauana                 Riley Leo Lauana
3     Adam Marry                 Adam Blake Marry
4     Martin Lues                Martin Smith
                                 Martin Flex Leo
```

In actual, both dataframe has more rows

Comment: anyone to answer this?